# How to delete a product's category Magento2

Tags: magento2, category, programmatically

I am trying to delete a product's category in magento 2 using the following code.

```
  public function deleteCategories($product_id){
        $categoryIds = $this->productCategory->getCategoryIds($product_id);
    
        $_product = $this->_productModel->load($product_id);
        $CategoryLinkRepository =  $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkRepositoryInterface');
        
        // all catgeories of a category
        $currentCategories  = $_product->getCategoryIds();
          foreach ($currentCategories as $categoryId) {
              try{
                    $CategoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds($categoryId, $_product->getSku());
              }catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_logger->info("Error importing stock for product sku: ".$_product->getSku().". ".$e->getMessage());
            }
         }
 }
```

But getting this error everytime.

```
Category does not contain specified product
```

Comment: before `$currentCategories  = $_product->getCategoryIds();` and just add `$currentCategories  = [];` it might be cache issue

Comment: Thanks for Reply @AmitBera. Now I'm not getting the error but categories are still not deleting.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but your code is correct. If you dump $categoryId and $_product->getSku() are there correct values there?

I tried to run these lines from a frontend controller in magento 2.4.1.

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkRepositoryInterface 
$categoryLinkRepository */
$categoryLinkRepository = $obj->create(\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkRepositoryInterface::class);
$result =  $categoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds(4, "24-MB03");
```

I ran this code on the sample data. Confirmed from backend that is was removed, added it again, ran the code again and it was removed again, so it works fine.